# Excel - Problems with Vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I can't get Vlookup to return the right value.

Below I'll post an example of what I'm talking about.

I need to find the correct UIN for an item in the first table and transfer it to the second table. I'm using the UPC to locate the item in the first table.

The Vlookup is in `J13`, the formula is `=VLOOKUP($I13,$G$2:$J$9,4)` so it should look for the UPC, `7142100247`, find it in `G2`, then return the value in `J2`. But it doesn't; it returns the value in `J9` and that makes me scratch my head and go "What the hell?"

Can anyone explain why it returns the wrong value and tell me how to get it to return the right one?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the cell formatting on the UPC numbers. Note that your UPCs in the lookup table at the top have leading zeroes, while the red UPC column does not. I was able to get your formula to work exactly as you posted it by applying a custom number format of Type: 00000000000 (i.e. eleven zeroes) to both the lookup table and to the red column.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The spreadsheet I need this to actually work on has 23000 rows and the UPCs are of varying lengths.

Comment: You should be okay still - it'll just go slower. As for the variable UPC length, if you find the longest possible number of digits and use that as the number of zeroes in your custom format, that should cover your bases.

The problem is, I think, arising because the values in the lookup table are not of the same type as those in the red area; another option could be making them all text strings in both places - the point is to make them the same.

Comment: I applied a custom number format of 11 0's to both columns and it still isn't working for me.

Comment: It could not be working for me because my UPC column in the red isn't a number, it's a contactation of column A and B. Because that table didn't come with a UPC field, it came with its UPCs separated into two fields so I had to contactate them to get a full UPC field and custom number formats don't seem to work on it.

Comment: That'll be the culprit. Try replacing "$I13" in your formula with "VALUE($I13)", so that it returns a number instead of a text string.

Comment: I'm having nothing but problems. I actually removed the concactations by copying them and pasting the values, so the concactations are gone and they're actually numbers now. Now it's just really screwy, the first row worked but the next two didn't, they had the same value and the next two have a different value, both of which are wrong. This is seriously confusing. Also, yes, both columns are now formatted exactly the same way.

Comment: I got it, I had to add FALSE as the fourth argument to the VLOOKUP function. That made it work.

Comment: Why then did you select this answer as the solution? It clearly does not present the solution to your problem. In fact, the suggestion of this answer is pure nonsense.

Comment: If someone submits a better solution I'll accept theirs since this one is incomplete. I only accepted it to indicate that my problem has been solved.

Comment: An answer should only be selected if it answers the question. You can always add your own answer and accept that as the solution. I've added a write-up of the solution approaches.

Answer (score 2):

The Vlookup is missing the fourth parameter, which means it will default to `TRUE`. This will always return a value, but not necessarily the one you want. Vlookup with `TRUE` as the fourth parameter requires the lookup table to be sorted ascending by the lookup column and will then return the first value that is either equal or less than the lookup value.

Using `False` as the last parameter, Vlookup will return only an exact match.

When you add `False` as the last parameter, you may see an #N/A error, which means that no exact match could be found.

In this case you need to check that the lookup value is in fact present in the data. Common problems are

- leading or trailing space characters in either the lookup column or the lookup value. In this case trim blanks from both the lookup column and the lookup value.
- mismatch of data type (e.g. lookup value is a number but the lookup column contains text and vice versa). In this case make sure that the lookup value is of the same type as the lookup column (or change the lookup column data).

A numeric lookup value can only be found if the first column contains numbers. How these numbers are formatted (e.g. with leading zeroes or not) does not make any difference at all. In most cases, numbers with leading zeroes are in fact numbers stored as text. The green warning triangle in your screenshot is a dead giveaway for that.